# Why Javascript specification designer introduced microtask in promise

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

I know something about microtask and Promise, such as handler in `Promise.prototype.then` will be enqueued into microtask and excuted as soon as call stacks empty, and it may be used to avoid race condition or something else about concurrent.

but what would happen if we don't introduce microtask?

Comment: You ask what would happen if it was executed synchronously? Or what would happen if it was waiting a full frame? Or something else?

Comment: @kaiido what would happen if it was executed synchronously, and all about it

Comment: "all about it" is a bit broad, but simply put, you'd have undefined behavior in your code: With forcing execution after the js-execution, you can be sure that whatever should be synchronous inside your code will get executed before whatever should be async (.then callback). For instance `my_prom.then(dosomethingafter); dosomethingnow();` without this behavior, we couldn't tell for sure if `my_prom` was already resolved and thus if `dosomethingafter` fired before or after `dosomethingnow`

Comment: @kaiido I just imagine then handler as a callback and it will be called when Promise object is settled, so the "undefined behavior" is the key problem or could you show me code?

Comment: You can think about JS engine as a queue which is constantly being filled with events on the left and emptied by the JS engine which reads them on the right and calls the handlers for each of these events one after another. Every time you call the Promise it will be written to the queue. JS engine can not work without its queue.

Comment: @IVOGELOV that's not that easy. Promises callbacks are not pushed to the queue, they are unshifted there, in what is called a micro-task, there can be as many such microtasks unshifted as needed, which is not the same as more conventional queuing like for events or timeouts for instance, which will get executed in the next event loop. https://jsfiddle.net/tbvfyrps/

Comment: @Kaiido Strictly speaking, events or timeouts may be executed in the 2nd, 3rd or later loop if you keep unshifting Promises to the queue. Microtasks are quite well explained in https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: @IVOGELOV I never said the contrary, but *strictly* speaking, what you are describing is the [spin the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) algorithm, and could very happen within anywhere in the js execution, from normal js execution, event handlers, Promises callbacks etc. The queue is only emptied one task at a time, when the first finished.

Comment: @Kaiido I am not contradicting you - just making a clarification that if you constantly unshift promises to the head of the queue this constantly delays the execution of events and timers which are pushed to the tail of the queue.

Comment: Yes, just like if you ran a while loop in an event handler, you'd delay all the coming ones.

Comment: What is the alternative to microtask you would think of? Interrupting the currently running code?

Comment: @trincot in my opinion the `then handler` is just a callback, it could be fired whenever Promise resolved. when the executor in Promise constructor resolved promsie object synchronously(just like `new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('foo'))`) and people haven't call then to give promise callback, without microtask the callback will never executed, so: 1, microtask just for sync executor. 2, `resolve` equeue something into microtask. it's just my rough idea, am I  right?

Comment: The executor runs immediately without microtask. The call to `resolve` creates a microtask. But how would you specify that an API, having a non-JS, low-level implementation, would trigger the resolution of a promise (that it exposes to JS via its API) if not by putting something in a queue? What alternative do you imagine in such scenario? Did you imagine it would potentially *interrupt* running JS code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take this example code:

```
Promise.resolve("resolved").then(i => console.log("resolved"));
console.log("start");
```

This is an immediately (synchronously) resolving promise. When the `then` method is executed it is already in a resolved state. Yet, the callback to `then` is not executed immediately. Instead a job is put in the job queue (microtask). So we get this output:

```
start
resolved
```

Your question is whether it could have worked without such job scheduling, meaning the callback would be executed immediately so that the result would be:

```
resolved
start
```

With the example code this would indeed be a feasible alternative. But now take another example, where the promise is not resolved by JavaScript code, but by a lower-level event, deeply buried within an API that encapsulates this with a promise interface. Let's say it is some API to read file contents:

```
readFile(path).then((content) => console.log("file contents: " + content));
console.log("start of a lot of work");
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    // some work
}
console.Log("end of a lot of work");
```

So, according to the Promise specification this would output:

```
start of a lot of work
end of a lot of work
file contents: .....
```

Now assume for a moment that the loop of work takes 3 seconds to complete, and that the file reading API has an implementation that delegates most of the work to the operation system's functions. Those OS functions will run in line with the OS processing architecture, which often is some form of event-driven multi-tasking. The essence here, is that the OS will be able to progress on the file operations while the JS loop is also progressing.

Let's also assume that the file reading completes within 1 second. An event bubbles up from the OS to the non-JavaScript middleware of the API, ready to bubble up into the JavaScript "world". What should happen now? There are two options we can imagine:

1. A job is put on the job queue which signals that the promise is resolved and the `then` callback(s) need to be called. This is how it actually works.
2. The running JavaScript loop is *interrupted*, the promise returned by `readFile` resolves, and the `then` callback is called at that very moment. Once the callback finishes, the execution context that was interrupted gets restored, and continues to completion.

The latter kind of mechanics could lead to a whole chain of interruptions, where even the code in a `then` callback could be interrupted by yet another promise-resolution event, ...etc. This could lead to a build up of execution contexts that must be maintained like a stack. This would make code execution rather unpredictable, hard to debug, and vulnerable to stack overflows.

In my opinion these are the reasons why this option is undesirable, and why option 1 is what we have. And even though the second option would work fine for promises created purely with JavaScript -- not dependent on some lower level asynchronous behaviour -- it would be strange if those promises would have a different behaviour than the ones that are provided by APIs. They should all use the same behaviour when it comes to `then` callback execution and the use of a job queue.